# Url.Page creates wrong url

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

Have a look at this code:

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Page("/Account/ConfirmEmail", null, new { userId = user.Id, code }, Request.Scheme);
```

The result is this:

> http://localhost:5000/Account/Register?userId=614d16ae-4e95-4796-8d67-cb829e12585b&code=CfDJ8OeNFdnFCrtCsRU7ofatUuROudlTo%2BFQe84oAiL%2BPJSoYwGH9q1Xadg8XBbpOFg5DiRH1vDoGeQ8l3qIFHjB3NMM3ZDTlQexawj1b%2BJ7P6X3SHoBsYs7jLYwcfGQCbnk1SJA5koFkoDcWj04nsjzQlJMe8ttR0DFdi%2B6TTbWI8WkPBaS083O3aU%2BL2bbYGNwwikhrkbB0nHy4PRzK1LZuZo%3D&page=%2FAccount%2FConfirmEmail

Where does the Register come from? Why is it not Account/ConfirmEmail? I did create this in the Register method of Account controller, so I suppose register came from there, but why did it use that as opposed to what I passed in? I do see that it added it as a parameter at the very end, but why?

As far as I can tell, according to this, I did it right.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.page?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_UrlHelperExtensions_Page_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_IUrlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_Object_System_String_System_String_

I am using core 2.1 still.

EDIT: Their registration tutorial says the same thing as what I have above:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-register-login-and-logout

If I use `.Action` instead of `.Page` I get my desired result, but I would like to know why `.Page` acts differently.

Comment: `The result is this:` Tell us what you mean by **result**. Was that the value of `callbackUrl` (if so, how did you check this)? Was it the URL shown in the browser? Something else?

Comment: `If I use .Action instead of .Page I get my desired result,` Please show us that working code, so we can compare the two.

Comment: @mjwills by result i mean the value that I get back when I call that. I checked it by printing it to the console. Also take the same line of code I have in my question, remove the word .page and put the word .Action and then I get the correct URI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are all used to generate url, however,`Url.Action` is for MVC and `Url.Page` is for Razor Pages.You use the code in Account controller which `Url.Action` is needed.

Refer to [Url Generation for controller/action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#url-generation) and [Url Generation for pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#url-generation-for-pages)

In asp.net core 2.0,scaffold Identity uses the MVC while in asp.net core 2.1+, it uses Razor Pages.