# ASP.Net URL Page Helper for ASP.Net Identity Account Confirmation does not create the correct URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

The following code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

```
EmailConfirmationUrl = Url.Page(
"/Account/ConfirmEmail",
pageHandler: null,
values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
protocol: Request.Scheme);
```

generates the wrong URL (below). It should have /Identity/Account/ConfirmEmail as path. How do I fix code above so that I get the right path?

https://localhost:5001/?area=Identity&userId=d83c48d3-2715-4dc1-84d7-6e1c1cb0ae4a&code=Q2ZESjhGeERhR0hlUThoTHNqRU9iU3hLTDRJcUtaTVI0S2UrSFFMbjQvL0lhUVVkZ1dqL2dPWkVNQ3lHdGkweU5CWmdSdXM4NVE3Z0hhMWp0TWJGU0h4bFh6ZmhGVWRkNm5MbTg2VXRhTjNpTWozSUVreVlmMEdyUUF0QUJ2MVdNV0Y5aWtTRW05bGdMcXhqTk93TkoxeXNaSW9qWFhkeHN1TkNRK0lISXJnVjVIRFJNTVNaTWRDR1FjaVhoRDFXNllqcnVpYXV2ajNONlp5L1BBUnVKdzkreEt2aFh5emMxa0lhWmNJWk0zcG9DSmN2bzRwODl5Uko2NmRleVNCVUtyQnl5dz09&page=%2FAccount%2Fhttps%3A%2FBlazorWorld.com%2FAccount%2FConfirmEmail

Comment: The [generated project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#create-a-web-app-with-authentication) provides ASP.NET Core Identity as a Razor Class Library, Are you using the default identity?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54645558/579022) to a previously asked question.
Essentially Url.Page is for Razor actions.  Url.Action is for MVC.  Which type of pages are you using in your application?

If this helps you out, be sure to go give Ryan an upvote on his answer.